# Will I lose my progress if I press "quit game"?

Tags: lego-star-wars

What happens if I press “quit game”?
Will the game start from the beginning?
And will I need to pay again?
I'm on iPhone.

Comment: ...where is the "quit game" that you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

I used to play on Android a few years ago, and unless something has drastically changed, quitting only closes the app and has no effect on your game.

I'm not sure what you mean by "pay again". If you mean re-purchase the app, then no, it doesn't make sense that you would need to repurchase the app after quitting it.